# No response from WCF Service called via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, response

I know this question has been asked many times, but I have not been able to find any solution to my particular problem.

I have a WCF web service using webHttpBinding that I am trying to call from a web page via a jquery $.ajax() call.

```
serviceFailed = function (a, b, c) {
    alert('Failure: ' + c);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/KasraNet.Services.Centurian.WebService/CenturianAdmin.svc/bob",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processdata: true,
    error: serviceFailed,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('Success: ' + msg);
    }
});
```

When run, the success alert is fired, but the msg is null.

Using FireBug, I can see that the response is completely empty, whilst using HttpFox, the error NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI is returned.  I cant see how this is a cross browser issue as I'm going to localhost and the service is also running on the same machine (I have even tried to change *localhost* to the machine name without success).

The service is defined thus.

```
<OperationContract(), DataContractFormat()>
<WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Function bob() As String
```

The Request and Response headers for the ajax call are

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Origin: null

Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date: Fri, 13 May 2011 14:20:53 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 19
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm really starting to pull my hair out!

EDIT: 
Now what is interesting is if I paste the url into the browser address bar, a download is initiated with the results of the service method in json format.

Thanks
John

Comment: Is the sevice hosted on port 80? If not, it's still a same-origin policy violation.

Comment: dlev, excuse my ignorance, but how do I find out and if required, change it?

Comment: Since it works by typing the same address into the browser's address bar, it's not a port issue. You might want to try $.get(yourUrl, function(data) { alert("msg = " + data); }) and see if that works. Your additional options to .ajax might be affecting things.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error.
The data from HttpFox is

    00:00:04.299 0.094 417 206 GET 200 application/json (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI) http://localhost/KasraNet.Services.Centurian.WebService/CenturianAdmin.svc/bob?_=1305297962508

Comment: Weird. That error generally occurs when there's a cross-domain issue; can you give me the url you are using to access the site itself?

Comment: It is all done locally at home I'm afraid, so no public address.

Comment: That's fine, I don't want to actually access the site, I'm just curious what hostname you're using when accessing it.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the URL for the ajax call?
http://localhost/KasraNet.Services.Centurian.WebService/CenturianAdmin.svc/bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am a bit of a numb skull.

I got thinking about the cross-domain issue and realised I was opening a direct link to the file and not going through IIS.

Creating a VD and opening the page through this, the results I was expecting came back.

Thankyou for taking the time to look at this issue, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

The data in your request is most likely the problem:

- Your WCF function doesn't expect any input data.
- Since you pass a string as the data (it looks like an empty JSON object but it's in fact a string), jQuery will append it to the URL like this: `http://localhost/KasraNet.Services.Centurian.WebService/CenturianAdmin.svc/bob?{}` But that's an invalid URL and IIS will reject it.

Comment: I've tried this method without the input data, and I've also tried it on a method that does require data.  Unfortunately, the same problem.